# ADF request from REST API within a time frame

Tags: azure-data-factory, rest

Assume that data needs to fetched by ADF using REST API and data is in JSON format.

Now for my call to REST API I have a time limit of say 45 seconds.

If source JSON file has say 1 million records then using parameters I can fetch only subset of this data.

But if my query via ADF exceeds 45 seconds then I should be able to receive a pre-defined message with an error code that I am requesting too much data and should refine my query criteria.
ADF should be able to receive this message with the code while processing the request.

How can this be achieved in ADF?

Thx

Comment: So the ADF instance is calling the API that returns the results to ADF? Where is the query defined? And shouldn't the API return an error that to much information is requested? You can use the `Wait Activity` to wait a second control flow that will return a default message.

Comment: Thx for your response.

ADF will be issuing query via REST API call.
And the time window is 45 seconds.
If the API call returns the error then how to capture that in ADF and 
then send a pre-defined message to an email id.

How to achieve this functionality in ADF?

Thx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the objective is to always return a message, either the succesful response by the REST API or a default message in case of an API error.

You can create dependencies between activities, check [Meagan Longoria blogpost on Azure Data Factory Activity Failures](https://datasavvy.me/2021/02/18/azure-data-factory-activity-failures-and-pipeline-outcomes/) for more information.

[image: Activity dependencies, source: https://datasavvy.me/2021/02/18/azure-data-factory-activity-failures-and-pipeline-outcomes/]

The orange dependency will only be executed when the Web Activity returns an error. You can set here the default message.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question and comment is, You want to send error message as email notification.

There is no *Send Email Activity* in Azure Data Factory. To get error message as email notification, You have to Create Logic app and then use it in ADF.

Follow below 2 articles by [Koen Verbeeck](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlserverauthor/114/koen-verbeeck/)

First link gives step by step procedure to create Logic app and Second link gives steps to send error message as email notification.

[Azure Data Factory Pipeline Email Notification](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5718/azure-data-factory-pipeline-email-notification-part-1/)

[Send Notifications from an Azure Data Factory Pipeline](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5962/send-notifications-from-an-azure-data-factory-pipeline-part-2/)